# R Shiny reactive time to trigger at specific time and not specific interval

Tags: r, shiny

Hopefully a simple question. I have a line like this in a shiny app that works fine:

```
autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(120000)
```

Is there anyway to set an event to execute say every 5 minutes on the minute and not just set intervals apart? So for example if the app is launched at 6:03pm it will execute the reactive element at 6:05pm then 6:10pm then 6:15pm etc.

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on the reactive element you are trying to update, but you could conceivably do this with reactive polling and `floor_date` from the `lubridate` package.

So, you'd have some reactive element that relies on data supplied by a `reactivePoll` function, and this data updates at every 5 minute interval, like so:

```
data <- reactivePoll(intervalMillis = 60000, session,
                        checkFunc = function() {
                          #check the time, rounded down to the previous 5 minute interval
                          lubridate::floor_date(Sys.time(), "5 mins")
                        },

                        valueFunc = function() {
                          #if checkFunc value has changed since the last check, return some updated value or updated dataset
                          get_value()                          
                        }
)
```

Comment: But so what does intervalMillis = 60000 do now? regarding that its executed every 5 minutes?